# Mirroring Files/Folders on Nas, Similar to Google Drive Sync

Tags: windows-8, nas, cloud-storage, mybook

I would like to create something similar to Google Drive with my NAS (MyBook Live).

Where I can have a local copy and if I modify it, the changes are made on the NAS. Periodically it would check and make sure if the files are in sync.

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

I'm using Windows 8.1 as my OS, and MyBookLive.

EDIT:

While both answers by Jason C and Journeyman Greek work, I found the bitSync to be a easier-to-implement option, so for my Journeyman Greek's option was "correct".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitorrent Sync's [Power PC port](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync/downloads) will reportedly work with mybook live - they have a bunch of scripts, and [sane settings here](http://community.wd.com/t5/My-Book-Live/BitTorrent-Sync-installation-script/td-p/588057). It has a web ui on the linux side, and clients for nearly every common system you may come across including windows. Its reasonably fast, and data is encrypted, and sent via bitorrent (which means files are tested for integrity at chunk level *as it uploads*).

Answer (score 1):

You could mount the network drive on boot then use e.g. [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) on a regular schedule to keep it sync'd with your local drive with minimal data transfer. DeltaCopy is like rsync for Windows and is precisely designed for the task you describe.

There are step-by-step instructions for doing this [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/rsync-for-windows-deltacopy/). In your case you'd have the DeltaCopy client and server both on the local machine, and the mounted network drive would be the backup location.

Another alternate option is regular nightly backups; for example, personally, I have a 4TB Seagate Central that I back up all my machines in my house to nightly using [Acronis TrueImage](http://www.acronis.com/en-us/personal/pc-backup/) (the backups are incremental and while Acronis stores proprietary archive files instead of the actual files, it also installs a shell extension to make the archives browsable in explorer). This also has the advantage of providing the ability to compress the backed up data, and the incremental backups allow a long history of backups to be maintained at once with minimal space (my own set up has nightly backups from the past 30 days available at any given time without any space issues). You have to pay for the software but it's worth it in my opinion.

The latter option may be more hassle-free to set up. I do not know what difficulties, if any, may be involved in setting up DeltaCopy on Windows 8.

Edit: Also having the backup history, as in the latter option, is important because with e.g. DeltaCopy if you don't have a history and you accidentally destroy or modify a file, you don't have an old version to revert to.

Comment: Is there any thing you dont reccomend copying

Comment: @Exikle There's nothing wrong with copying everything if you have the space for it. I do a full backup (with Acronis) of every partition on my drives so that if the drive fails I can restore the data to a new drive and just move on with my life without having to e.g. reinstall Windows and such. But if space is at a premium or you don't care about having that ability, the general good idea would be to back up anything that isn't replaceable: your personal documents, etc. (whereas the Windows system folder, for example, can be restored just by reinstalling Windows).

Comment: @Exikle Also see the little note I added in an edit. When choosing a backup strategy don't forget to consider whether or not you want the ability to easily restore older versions of files (very useful in case you, say, accidentally delete or overwrite an important document, or something damages it).